# Memory issue processing large image files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, imagemagick, aws-lambda, graphicsmagick

I am processing image files in AWS Lambda with GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick, node.js. Some of the files are > 200MB in size which causes the Lambda function to hit memory limits. I have set the maximum memory of 1.5GB.

The log file displays:
REPORT RequestId: xxx Duration: 23200.51 ms Billed Duration: 23300 ms Memory Size: 1536 MB Max Memory Used: 1536 MB

Code:

```
async.series([
    function getOriginalSize(p_next) {
        // size
        gm(s3_img.Body).size(function (err, size) {
            if (!err) {
                width_orig = size.width;
                height_orig = size.height;
                p_next(null, 'getOriginalSize');
            }
        });
    },
    function identify(p_next) {
        gm(s3_img).flatten();
        gm(s3_img.Body).identify(function(err, id_info){
            // THIS IS WHERE THE FOLLOWING ERROR OCCURS:
            // { [Error: Command failed: ] code: null, signal: 'SIGKILL' }
            ...
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
]);
```

I have not found an answer to this and would be grateful for any kind of tips or comments.

Comment: the file size is basically irrelevant. what it comes down to is the image resolution. e.g. a 5000x5000 solid color image becomes a 107kb PNG/383kb JPG. but in raw bitmap form in memory will require 5k*5k*3bpp =~ 72megabytes of ram.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have checked the resolution but one example image that fails is a PSD file, has a resolution of around 5000x5000px and it still seems to need over 1,5GB in memory.

Comment: You seem to have removed precisely the piece of code that causes the error? What are you doing in the piece that causes the error? Have you tried limiting the memory available to ImageMagick so that it pages out to disk instead?

Comment: a psd can literally be hundreds of images internally, the resolution there means even less. e.g. it could be a 999999x9999999 image, with a small layer that only lets a 10x10 chunk show through. it can be multiple layers, each with its own image, blah blah blah.